# NGINX dynamic location | alias

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have a driver i need to distribute to my users, using an angular website, till here is ok, but the problem is here. The download is handled by nginx using "location" like this:

```
    location /download/windows-driver.exe {
            alias /opt/dist/windows/driver-windows-64-1.0.0.exe;
            types { application/octet-stream; }
            default_type application/octet-stream;
            add_header Content-disposition "attachment";
    }

    location /download/linux-driver.run {
            alias /opt/dist/linux/driver-linux-amd64-1.0.0.run;
            types { application/octet-stream; }
            default_type application/octet-stream;
            add_header Content-disposition "attachment";
    }
```

Then my question is, every time i upgrade my driver version, should i go manually to nginx and change it? isn't there any way to make it dynamic?
I've been searching a way to make nginx use some unix commands to read the driver folder and user the latest version, but i have not been successful.

Any solution or clarification will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do this in Nginx. It might be simpler to use a symlink and always point it to the latest version.

Comment: How to do that?